# MySQL - Optimizing column referencing?

Tags: mysql, optimization, reference

I'm having difficulty trying to form the actual question I have, so hopefully I can get the point across with visual aid.

What I'm wondering is whether or not my current database design is horribly flawed, slightly inefficient, or ... correct.

Q: Is there a better way for a row cell to reference a column in another table, aside from just saving a string of that column's name?

Example:
There are two tables.

table01: has 3 columns - c_id, customer, tier (*tier holds the column name of a tier in table02* )

table02: has 5 columns - i_id, item, tier1, tier2, tier3

```
table01 +------+----------+------+
        |'c_id'|'customer'|'tier'|
        +------+----------+------+
        |   1  | John     | tier1|
        |   2  | Lisa     | tier2|
        |   3  | Mike     | tier1|
        |   4  | Tom      | tier3|
        +------+----------+------+

table02 +------+------+-------+-------+-------+
        |'i_id'|'item'|'tier1'|'tier2'|'tier3'|
        +------+------+-------+-------+-------+
        |   1  | apple| $1.99 | $2.99 | $3.99 |
        |   2  | chalk| $2.99 | $3.99 | $4.99 |
        |   3  | pens | $3.99 | $4.99 | $5.99 |
        |   4  | shirt| $4.99 | $5.99 | $6.99 |
        +------+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

**Result:**

```
John    +------+-------+
        | apple| $1.99 |
        | chalk| $2.99 |
        | pens | $3.99 |
        | shirt| $4.99 |
        +------+-------+
```

Selecting John's row would yield tier1, which is then used to query for table02.tier1, and grab that column's contents. (In this discounted prices for tier1 customers). The tier1 items would then be displayed with their correct prices.

***Is there a more efficient way to reference an outside table's column name, like... in the style of foreign keys? Where if the column name changes, then that information waterfalls to other linked data cells?*** Is my approach correct, or should I restructure how I'm doing things?

Comment: Is the `i_id` in `table02` joined with the `c_id` in `table01`?  If not, how do you decide which row in `table02` belongs with the row in  `table01`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't completely clear how the `c_id` and `i_id` columns are supposed to be used, but a more conventional design would be to use a design like this:

```
table01 +------+----------+------+
        |'c_id'|'customer'|'tier'|
        +------+----------+------+
        |   1  | John     |  1   |
        |   2  | Lisa     |  2   |
        |   3  | Mike     |  1   |
        |   4  | Tom      |  3   |
        +------+----------+------+

table02 +------+------+-------+
        |'i_id'|'tier'|'cost' |
        +------+------+-------+
        |   1  |   1  | $1.99 |
        |   2  |   1  | $2.99 |
        |   3  |   1  | $3.99 |
        |   4  |   1  | $4.99 |
        |   1  |   2  | $2.99 |
        |   2  |   2  | $3.99 |
        |   3  |   2  | $4.99 |
        |   4  |   2  | $5.99 |
        |   1  |   3  | $3.99 |
        |   2  |   3  | $4.99 |
        |   3  |   3  | $5.99 |
        |   4  |   3  | $6.99 |
        +------+------+-------+
```

---

> I edited the example to better exemplify my thoughts. Which really doesn't change your answer much. So it'd be better to consolidate the tier columns into one column and just repeat the item id (i_id) data several times? My reasoning behind breaking the tier/cost structure into columns was to cut down on redundancy. Would that approach require me to make a new table to index the tiers for foreign keys?

I understand what you're doing now.  Somewhere along the line, you might have a 'Sales' table which records a `c_id`, and `i_id`, a quantity, a date and other such information (if each sale consists of one item; otherwise, you'd have an 'Orders' table and an 'OrderItems', and the `c_id` would be associated with the orders table and the `i_id` would be associated with order items, and there'd be an order number to connect the two tables).

If you add your `item` desciption to the revised `table02` above, you would be violating 3NF.  You should have a table such as 'Products' with the `i_id` and `item` columns.  This would give names to item numbers.  The `table02` (maybe 'TieredItemCosts') table I proposed would remain as it is; the primary key is the combination of (`i_id`, `tier`).

Comment: Yea, I just edited the example to better exemplify my thoughts. Which really doesn't change your answer much.


So it'd be better to consolidate the tier columns into one column and just repeat the item id (i_id) data several times?


My reasoning behind breaking the tier/cost structure into columns was to cut down on redundancy.


Would that approach require me to make a new table to index the tiers for foreign keys?

Comment: I think you nailed it on the revised structure.  The HOW relationship is actually simple.  C_ID is the customer... A customer can have different pricing levels they are charged... A large reseller could have heavy discounts vs an occaisional seller vs random direct buyer.  That said, any product in the "ITEM" (I_id) can be sold to the customer, but at the tier level that customer is entitled to base on their "buying power" agreements.

Comment: @DRapp Exactly. Which is why I was wondering how to structure the relation. Would my current approach be appropriate, or would Jonathan's approach be better?

Comment: Most DBMS do not support a way of selecting a value from a column name whose name is itself stored in a column value.  If you read the right bit of the literature, you'd find a proposal for a function 'CWNI' (column whose name is), but it is not implemented in most systems.  Hence, I believe you'll be obliged to use a variant on the scheme I proposed.  Notice that if you could use your column-name scheme, then different rows in the results would be pulling values from different columns.  Or you'd be obliged to write a 3-way disjoint UNION, one term of which would select the 'tier1' values, ...

Comment: I see your wisdom Jon, thank you much. :) I was worried about maintainability earlier, but in the long run conventional wisdom is, once again, correct. Thank you very much, sometimes I tend to over think simple issues. xD